# Mercado Pago: Error en Checkout Básico

Tags: mercadopago

Cuando llego al paso de confirmar pago, al hacer click en el botón **Pagar**, Sale un mensaje de error `Tuvimos un problema, intenta nuevamente.`

Con PHP, creo la preferencia de la siguiente manera:

```
$items = [];
    foreach ($factura->items as $itemFactura) {
        $item = (!empty($itemFactura->promocion))? $itemFactura->promocion : ((!empty($itemFactura->carpeta))? $itemFactura->carpeta : null);
        if ($item) {
            $items[] = [
                'Title' => $item->nombre,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'currency_id' => 'ARS',
                'unit_price' => $item->valor_final
            ];
        }
    }
    $payer = [
        'name' => $cliente->nombre,
        'email' => $cliente->contacto_principal->email
    ];
    $preference = [
        'items' => $items,
        'payer' => $payer,
        'external_reference' => $factura->id,
        'notification_url' => env('PUBLIC_URL_ADMIN') .'/' . self::NPI_URI,
        'back_urls' => [
            'success' => env('PUBLIC_URL_RADIO') .'/perfil/resumen?resultado-pago=pago-exitoso',
            'failure' => env('PUBLIC_URL_RADIO') .'/perfil/resumen?resultado-pago=pago-fallido',
            'pending' => env('PUBLIC_URL_RADIO') .'/perfil/resumen?resultado-pago=pago-pendiente'
        ]
    ];

    $mpPreference = $this->mp->create_preference($preference);
    return $mpPreference['response']['init_point'];
```

Estoy usando dos test users, uno para el vendedor y otro para el comprador:

```
Seller: {"id":310041833,"nickname":"TESTY4SEPEJH","password":"qatest7969","site_status":"active","email":"test_user_57983662@testuser.com"}%
Buyer1: {"id":310038803,"nickname":"TETE5740407","password":"qatest6853","site_status":"active","email":"test_user_54630865@testuser.com"}%
```

Creé ambos usuarios de la siguiente manera:

```
AT=`curl -s -X POST -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 'https://api.mercadopago.com/oauth/token' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -d 'client_id=1702625825130154' -d 'client_secret=R8VTr33n7NWNGIH8r4yQfWuA6K6GHmBC' | grep -o '"access_token":"[^"]*"' | sed -n 's/.*"access_token":"\(.*\)"/\1/p'`

curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://api.mercadopago.com/users/test_user?access_token=$AT" \
-d '{"site_id":"MLA"}'
```

Me podrían dar una mano y decirme que puedo estar haciendo mal? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Saludos! Se me presenta el mismo problema , lograste solventarlo? Gracias

Comment: Poner vacio la notificacion para probar 'notification_url' => ''